# Как в PonyORM сделать отложенную запись в БД?

Tags: python

Решил начать пользоваться  `PonyORM`. 
Не могу решить одну проблему. Как сделать отложную запись в базу данных?

Например: 
Есть у меня поставщик, я открываю окно с поставщиком меняю ему реквизиты, и после этого решаю сохранить данные или нет. Но `Pony` не позволяет изменять класс поставщика без `@db_session`, а если поставить `@db_session` то он сразу все комитит. В таком случае я не могу отменить изменения.
Хотелось бы классу `Vendor` дописать методов, и пользоваться им как полноценным классом. (надеюсь понятно выразился)

Сделал небольшой примерчик.

```
class VendorWindow():
    @db_session
    def __init__(self, order_id):
        self.vendor = Vendor[order_id]

    def ui_new_name(self, name):  # Изменение имени поставщика
        self.vendor.name = name

    def ui_new_phone(self, number):  # Изменение номера поставщика
        self.vendor.phone = number

    def ui_accept(self):  # Принять изменеия
        pass  # тут надо закомитить изменения

    def ui_cancel(self):  # Не применяит изменеия
        pass  # тут надо просто закрыть окно без изменений в БД
# В отдельном файле
class Vendor(db.Entity):
   id = PrimaryKey(int, auto=True)
   name = Required(str)
   full_name = Optional(str)
   mail = Optional(str)
   phone = Optional(str)
```

Comment: Почему бы вам не поменять действия местами — сперва решить, менять или нет, а уже потом менять реквизиты? Что мешает?

Comment: Заведите, например, временный словарь, в котором будут храниться «неуверенные» изменения, а когда решите, что нужно сохранить изменения, тогда уже меняйте данные через Pony

Comment: Да это конечно вариант! Но таких данных может быть много + могут быть связи такие как адреса, контакты, места разгрузки и т.д. А так можно было бы работать с классом поставщик. Тем более что в пони это очень удобно реализовано.

Comment: Ну, в любом случае задача ORM (не только Pony) — предоставлять содержимое базы данных тем или иным образом. Когда вы меняете данные через ORM, это подразумевает, что вы уже твёрдо решили обновить базу, и если ORM не сохраняет изменения в базе сразу, то только ради оптимизации производительности. И вам наверное стоит придумать какую-нибудь такую организацию своего предположение, чтобы такое отношение к ORM было и на практике без вот этих вот отмен

Comment: Хотя вообще есть `rollback()`, который может подойти вам как «быстрое» решение проблемы, но он откатит все изменения, сделанные внутри `@db_session`, и лично мне очень не нравится применять его без крайней необходимости

Comment: Да придумать не проблема. Просто я думал может за меня уже все придумано)
Мне тоже не очень это нравиться. Но у меня не получилось с rollback(). Как только я выхожу из метода ui_new_name изменения сразу комитятся!

Comment: Значит вы где-то выходите из `@db_session`, а где — это уже вам виднее, соответствующего кода вы не показали

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Списался с Александром (создатель Pony). Он дал мне ответ что использовать Pony класс как промежуточный нельзя!